# A subset of a countable set is countable

Tags: real-analysis

Below is what I said, is it right?
let A be a subset of B, so|A|<|B|
since B is countable, |B|<|N|, which implies that |A|<|N|, so there exists a surjection from N to A, thus A is countable.

Comment: Maybe $\le$ is a more appropriate symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure about your notation.
In any case, I think you can argue more elementary.
By definition, $A$ is countable if there is an injection
\begin{align*}
A\rightarrow\mathbb{N}
\end{align*}
Since $B$ is countable, we have an injection
\begin{align*}
B \xrightarrow{\phi} \mathbb{N}.
\end{align*}
The inclusion is also injective
\begin{align*}
A \hookrightarrow B.
\end{align*}
so that the composition gives us the desired injection
\begin{align*}
A \hookrightarrow B \xrightarrow{\phi}\mathbb{N}.
\end{align*}
If your definition requires a surjection $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow A$ then you can argue similarly.

Comment: Why is the inclusion also injective?

Comment: You can prove that directly:
If $A\subset B$ then the inclusion $i:A \hookrightarrow B$
is defined via $i(a)=a$.
So, if $i(a)=i(a')$ then $a=a'$, hence it is injective.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use $|A|<|B|$ or $|A|<|{\Bbb N}|$ in this case, there is no comparing infinite quantities. You have to argue by making a map from $B$ to $A$ or from $\Bbb N$ to $A$.

Comment: Well, actually, there *is* comparison through Cantor-Schroder-Bernstein, but this sort of exercise is exactly what goes into a proof of Cantor-Schroder-Bernstein.

Comment: so how to prove it?

Comment: @Matthew You have to argue by making a map from B to A or from N to A.

Answer (score 0):

This claim cannot be proved, unless you make one of two corrections:

1. the subset is also infinite, or
2. the subset is at most countable.

In the first case, exists a injection from the subset $A$ to the set $B$. Since $B$ is countable, exists a bijection from $B$ to $\Bbb N$; in particular it is a injection. Thus, composing this injections we obtain a injection from $A$ to $\Bbb N$,
as desired.

In the second case, if the subset is infinite, we proceed as first case. If it is finite, obviusly, exists a bijection to $\{i \in \Bbb N : 1 \le i \le n\}$ for some $n \in \Bbb N$.